# Property 'PasswordInput' doesn't exist on Carbon/react TextInput type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, carbon-design-system

im trying to use carbon/react on my react/typescript project, Im facing an issue where is typescript doesn't know **PasswordInput** propety on **TextInput** component, even tho the code **works** fine.
this is my code:

```
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, TextInput } from "@carbon/react";

function App() {
  return (
    <Form>
      <FormGroup legendText="FormGroup Legend">
        <TextInput id="one" labelText="email" type="email" />
        <TextInput.PasswordInput
          id="two"
          labelText="password"
          type="password"
        />
        <Button>Submit</Button>
      </FormGroup>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i get a typescript error in **TextInput.PasswordInput** says:

```
Property 'PasswordInput' does not exist on type
 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<TextInputProps & RefAttributes<unknown>>'
```

this is docs link of how to use password input: [textinput toggle password visibility](https://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/components-textinput--toggle-password-visibility)